# Different yml files for different Beans in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, resources, yaml

In my spring boot application, I have the main application.yml file. I have a lot of properties, and therefore I would like to have another yml files, which contains the specified properties, grouped by their logic or something.

How can I configure a Bean, to load and work all the properties from one new yml file, and another Bean from another new yml? What is the best practice for it?

I found examples using `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean`, and this bean can read several resources (yml files), but in an another Bean, when I autowire this `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean`, I cannot get that specific yml, because the `getObject()` of this `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` will have all the yml resources I added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have it! This is how it works:

I have a properties configuration class, which loads the yml files:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

    public static final String PERSONS_FILE_NAME = "persons.yml";
    public static final String FOODS_FILE_NAME = "foods.yml";

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean personsYaml = personsPropertiesFromYamlFile();
        final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean foodsYaml = foodsPropertiesFromYamlFile();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setPropertiesArray(personsYaml.getObject(), foodsYaml.getObject());
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(PersonsManager.QUALIFIER_NAME)
    public YamlPropertiesFactoryBean personsPropertiesFromYamlFile() {
        final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource(PERSONS_FILE_NAME));
        return yaml;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(FoodsManager.QUALIFIER_NAME)
    public YamlPropertiesFactoryBean foodsPropertiesFromYamlFile() {
        final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource(FOODS_FILE_NAME));
        return yaml;
    }

}
```

And finally, I have two beans (managers), which hold only the corresponding yml properties:

```
@Component
public class PersonsManager extends YmlPropertiesManager {

    public static final String QUALIFIER_NAME = "personsYaml";

    @Autowired
    public PersonsManager(@Qualifier(QUALIFIER_NAME) YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlObject) {
        super(yamlObject);
    }

    ...

}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class FoodsManager extends YmlPropertiesManager {

    public static final String QUALIFIER_NAME = "personsYaml";

    @Autowired
    public FoodsManager(@Qualifier(QUALIFIER_NAME) YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlObject) {
        super(yamlObject);
    }

    ...

}
```

So the main thing here is the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Beans shouldn't be aware of yaml files. The yaml files are just sources that use used to build up the Spring Environment instance.

If you want specific properties for specific beans, the best way is to prefix those properties in application.yaml, and then use the @ConfigurationProperties with an argument of the prefix you want to use, to bind those properties to the bean in question.

See here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html